# Gnuplot key horizontal spacing

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot and am trying to increase the horizontal spacing between the columns in the key.  I have tried the following, but it hasn't helped to increase the spacing between the columns.  (Spacing only does vertical).

```
set key font "hershey, 10"
set key left
set key vertical maxrows 10
set key samplen 10
```

However, the samplen doesn't increase the gap between the columns, it only makes the lines in the keylonger.

[image: Gnuplot key]

I am using:

```
G N U P L O T
Version 5.0 patchlevel 3    last modified 2016-02-21
```

So, how would I increase the gap?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably try

```
set key width 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, it works for me

```
set key spacing 5
```